# c++ template specialisation method definition

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

The following code works fine, a simple template class with a definition and a use

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class foo{
  public:
  string what();
};

template<class T> string foo<T>::what(){
  return "foo of type T";
}

int main(){
  foo<int> f;
  cout << f.what() << endl;
}
```

If I then add the following (above main, but after the declaration of template class foo;)

```
template<> class foo<char>{
public:
  string what();
};
template<> string foo<char>::what(){
  return "foo of type char";
}
```

I get an error from g++

> Line 19: error: template-id 'what<>'
>   for 'std::string foo::what()'
>   does not match any template
>   declaration

Here is a codepad the shows the error: http://codepad.org/4HVBn9oJ

What obvious misstake am I making? Or is this not possible with c++ templates?
Will defining all the methods inline (with the defintion of template<> foo) work?

Thanks again all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<> class foo<char>{
public:
  string what();
};
/*template<>*/ string foo<char>::what(){
  return "foo of type char";
}
```

You don't need that `template<>`. `foo<char>` is already a complete type after it's specialized.

Comment: The `what<>` in the error message hints this. Always read the error messages carefully. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: or cry for the lack of explicitness :/

Comment: Accepted because it included the reason and was first. I was (incorrectly) mimicking the form of specializing a template. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Writing this as:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class foo{
  public:
  string what();
};

template<class T> string foo<T>::what(){
  return "foo of type T";
}

template<> class foo<char>{
public:
  string what();
};

string foo<char>::what(){
  return "foo of type char";
}

int main(){
  foo<char> f;
  cout << f.what() << endl;
}
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> If I then add the following (above main, but before the declaration of template class foo;)

Define the specialization **after** the generic class template.

By the time the compiler sees the specialization, it first needs to know the class template of which this is a specialization. So logically, the specialization should appear **after** the generic class template.

Comment: Sorry it should have said AFTER not before, if you had looked at the codepad this would have been clear. Thank you for your time anyway.